# 'site.com didn't send any data' using django

Tags: python, django, project-reactor, pythonanywhere

I have a Django webapp that takes a name and triggers a scrapy spider depending on the given name. My app works perfectly when I run it on localhost, but when trying to deploy it via PythonAnywhere.com I get an error message (on the browser, not the logs) that reads

(translated)

> This page does not work
>
> azservices.pythonanywhere.com did not send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

my views.py file is as follows:

```
def index(request):

THIS_FOLDER = Path(__file__).parent.parent.resolve()
print(f'THIS_FOLDER is: {THIS_FOLDER}')

if request.method == "POST":

    artist = request.POST.get("artist")
    print(f'artist is: {artist}')
    try:
        # configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
        crawler = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
        q = crawler.crawl(PostsSpider, artist=artist)
        q.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

        reactor.run()

        #download the XLSX file
        file_path = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'output.xlsx')
        print(f'file path is:{file_path}')
        response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename='output.xlsx')
        print('hallo, ik ben zelfs hier')
        return response
    except Exception as e:
            print('Error', str(e))


return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Through some extremely advanced commenting out code and print statements, I am confident that the code gets stuck at 'reactor.run()'

Why do I get this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Could it be cors problem?

Comment: @davidbackx I have no idea what that means, should I...? : (

Comment: If reactor.run starts threads, that will not work in a web app. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/ for how to move that code out of your web app

Comment: @Glenn I do think this would solve my problem, but do I have to set up a redis server as well? It seems like a cumbersome solution for this problem.